# Firefox gives error when displaying an iframe with a chart in a Bootsrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I create a site with a Bootstrap carousel. In this carousel I try to show two iframes with a site whitch contains a chart from chartjs.org.

On Firefox 91.1.0esr (32-Bit) I get this error:

```
Uncaught 
Exception { name: "NS_ERROR_FAILURE", message: "", result: 2147500037, filename: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.1/dist/chart.min.js", lineNumber: 13, columnNumber: 0, data: null, stack: "fit@https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.1/dist/chart.min.js:13:146316
```

The error does not appear in Chrome and Edge. Is it a Bug in Firefox?

The site with the carousel:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="5000">
      <iframe src="./site.html" title="Iframe1"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="5000">
      <iframe src="./site.html" title="Iframe2"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The site with the chart:

```js
const labels = [
            'January',
            'February',
            'March',
            'April',
            'May',
            'June',
        ];

        const data = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
            }]
        };

        const config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: data,
            options: {}
        };


        const myChart = new Chart(
            document.getElementById('diagramm'),
            config
        );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="diagramm"></canvas>
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It is because of the display none. But unfortunately I don't have a solution yet.